# Не запускается программа Katalon Studio под Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ide

Программа https://katalon.com. Собственно скачал и распаковал архив tar.gz, после пытаюсь запустить файл `katalon` через терминал `./katalon`, появляется окно программы и потом закрывается, в консоли ничего нет.

Comment: По этой программе вам скорее помогут в комьюнити https://forum.katalon.com/ чем тут на SO

Comment: Ну судя по тому, что написано тут: https://github.com/katalon-studio/katalon-studio/blob/master/install.sh - сначала нужно запустить под root, ибо хочет `mkdir /opt/`. А учитывая, что в `katalon.ini` есть строка `plugins/org.eclipse` - эта фигня написана на эклипсе, а значит в систему надо поставить `jre\jdk` от Оракла или `Corretto` от Amazon. В общем - я бы сначала поднял бы виртуалку и попробовал поковырять прогу там. Потому что есть вероятность уфигачить основную ОС мусором.

Comment: Спасибо проблема была в jdk нужно было поставить нужную версию